# Porqué Dapper no mapea el objeto?

Tags: c#, dapper

estoy usando Dapper en c# aspnet Core para realizar una consulta en Sqlpostgres y que me retorne el objeto con todos sus valores completos y mapeados desde la base de datos. Pero hay un problema cuando son varios joins, y no me completa correctamente uno de los objetos.

El objeto es Persona, y a su vez tiene varios atributos que se completan correctamente. Pero los objetos: EstadoCivil, TipoIdentificador y Genero se completan excepto uno. El que no se completa esta relacionado al orden en el cual establesco el mapeo.
Ejmplo: Si pongo  map: (persona, estadocivil, genero, **tipoidentificador**) entonces el objeto "tipoidentificador" dentro de "Persona", no se completa. Y Si pongo: map: (persona, estadocivil, tipoidentificador, **genero**), entonces el objeto genero no se completa...Es como si el último Objeto no lo pudiera hacer.

Las pruebas las realicé siempre con la misma persona de la base de datos y los atributos se traen correctamente, la query se ejecuta y trae todos los datos.

La función es:
public async Task find (int id)
{

```
        var sql_query = @"SELECT      a.*,
                                      b.*,
                                      c.*,
                                      d.*
                            FROM public.""Personas"" as a 
                                left join
                                    public.""Estadociviles"" as b
                                on a.""IdEstadoCivil"" = b.""Id""
                                left join
                                    public.""Tipoidentificadores"" as c    
                                on a.""IdTipoIdentificador"" = c.""Id""
                                left join
                                    public.""Generos"" as d    
                                on a.""IdGenero"" = d.""Id""
                            WHERE a.""Id"" = @Id";
```

using (var connection = dbConnection())
{

```
            var oPersona = await connection.QueryAsync<Persona, Estadocivil,  Genero, Tipoidentificador, Persona>(sql_query,
                                           map: (persona, estadocivil, genero, tipoidentificador) =>
                                           {
                                               persona.Estadocivil = (Estadocivil)estadocivil;                                                   
                                               persona.Tipoidentificador = (Tipoidentificador)tipoidentificador;
                                               persona.Genero = (Genero)genero;

                                               return persona;
                                           }, 
                                           param: new { id },
                                           splitOn: "Id,Id,Id").ConfigureAwait(false);
            return (Persona) oPersona.FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }
```

Ejecutandolo queda:
{
"id": 3,
"nombre": "Jose David",
"razonSocial": null,
"apellido": "Galiano",
"fecNacimiento": null,
"idLocalidad": 2204,
"barrio": null,
"direccion": "san martin",
"nroDireccion": 702,
"dpto": "78",
"piso": 1,
"telcelular": "03472",
"telfijo": null,
"email": null,
"tipoidentificador": null,
"nroIdentificacion": 25656558,
"tipoPersona": "M",
"genero": {
"id": 1,
"descripcion": "Masculino",
"fechaAlta": "2022-05-22T19:35:11.823046",
"usuarioAlta": "JGALIANO",
"fechaBaja": null,
"usuarioBaja": null
},
"ocupacion": "Empleado",
"estadocivil": {
"id": 1,
"descripcion": "Soltero",
"fechaAlta": "2022-05-22T19:32:48.288837",
"usuarioAlta": "JGALIANO",
"fechaBaja": null,
"usuarioBaja": null
},
"fechaAlta": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"usrAlta": JGALIANO,
"fechaBaja": null,
"usrBaja": null,
"fechaMod": null,
"usrMod": null
}

Comment: algo me dice, que el spliton no esta funcionando.. probaste generar campos dummy y hacer un split segun esos campos?

Comment: @gbianchi, me das un ejemplo de tu propuesta? Gracias!

Comment: en lugar de hacer split on Id, pone en el select columnas dummy para que dapper sepa bien por donde separar.. tipo select a.*, 1 as dummy1, b.*, 1 as dummy2 etc.... y hace el split por esas columnas dummy